# Let R be the real numbers and C be the complex numbers. Can CxC be made into a field as RxR can?

Tags: field-theory

There is no obvious way to do so and after several attempts I suspect the answer is no, but I can't see how you would show it. Is the reason because CxC is four dimensional ?

Comment: Not as an extension of $\mathbb{C}$ (because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed), but see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion.

Comment: What would you want the properties to be? The $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ has a natural inclusion $R\to \mathbb R\times\{0\}$. In theory, you can make the set $\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ into any field of the same cardinality, including $\mathbb R$, but it wouldn't be interesting in the same way. In particular, @QiaochuYuan's comment is correct about the inability to extend an algebraically closed field.

Comment: why won't using the same definition of multiplication as used in making RxR into a field work?

Comment: @mikebrady Jus try it and check the axioms.

Comment: @mike: you don't get a field that way. It's a nice exercise to check this.

Comment: Right, it took me a while to see it but (i,1), for example, would not have an inverse since i^2+1=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to a higher dimension, but you lose some properties of a field. You get the Quaternions(denoted $\mathbb{H}$), but it is no longer a field but a skew-field--it is non-commutiative.

Perhaps the following theorem of Frobenius is insightful here:

Let $\mathcal{A}\neq 0$ be an associative quadratic real algebra without  zero divisors, then there are three and only three possibilities:
1. $\mathcal{A}\cong \mathbb{R}$
2. $\mathcal{A}\cong \mathbb{C}$
3. $\mathcal{A}\cong \mathbb{H}$

You can go further to the octonians(8 dimensional $\mathbb{R}$ algebra), but you lose associatvity.  You only get an alternative division algebra.

I believe this is the farthest you can go if you want a division algebra.(or are there any other restrictions? Sorry I'm no expert here so if I claimed something wrong pls comment)

If you're interested in this topic I recommend the book ${\it Numbers}$ by Ebbinghaus(and others)

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb C\times\mathbb C$ is [called](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number) bicomplex numbers (or tessarines). It is commutative and associative and has all properties of a field except it has zero divisors.

You have an error in the question, $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to the set of [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) and also has zero divisors. It is thus also not a field.